# OptimizePress WordPress plugin error

Tags: wordpress

Since moving some site files from one domain to another (all files were on the same server, it just had a domain update).

when going to edit a page using the OptimizePress plugin, at the top of the live edit pane we are getting the following errors;

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'out' in /home/hosting/public_html/mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/optimizePressPlugin/lib/modules/blog/video/video.php on line 141

Warning: Illegal string offset 'new_options' in /home/hosting/public_html/mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/optimizePressPlugin/lib/modules/blog/video/video.php on line 141
```

I've tried reinstalling the plugin but i get the same warning messages? Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this please?

Answer (score 0):

This process/plugin has helped out us

https://help.optimizepress.com/article/1085-update-url-references-after-moving-domain

It basically involves installing ***another*** OptimizePress plugin that helps with admin tasks like moving domains. Your standard 'go live' style plugins don't do the job.

Hope this helps.